# Code Igniter form submit returns empty page

Tags: php, forms

I had this code dumped on me.  I know nothing about Code Ignitor and a little about php.  I have a form that returns a selected value.  However, when I click on the submit button, it returns back to the right page but with no code on it at all.  I cannot figure out where the problem is.  The claim does not seem to be going into the database by setting the user id so I don't think it's getting that far.  What can I try?

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="/sp/makeClaim">
  <div class="text-center" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <select name="spId">
      <option value="-1"<?php $this->printSelected($spId, -1);?>>-- Choose a Service Provider --</option>
      <?php
      foreach ($spData as $id => $name)
      {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"<?php $this->printSelected($spId, $id);?>><?php print($name); ?></option>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default sp" value="Make Claim from List Above" /><br />
    or<br />
    <a href="/sp/create/" class="btn btn-default sp">Add Your Service Provider Information</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

The controller code:

```
public function makeClaim()
{
  $formDefaults = array(
    'spId' => -1
  );

  if ($this->input->post())
  {
    foreach ($formDefaults as $key => $defaultValue)
    {
      $$key = trim($this->input->post($key));

      if ($spId == -1)
      {
        $this->addError('You must choose the service provider you wish to claim.');
      }
    }

    $sp = $this->getEm()->getRepository('Entities\ServiceProvider')->findOneBy(array('id' => $spId));
    if (is_null($sp))
    {
      $this->addError('A service provider with that ID could not be found.');
    }

    if (count($this->getErrors()) == 0)
    {
      $claim = new \Entities\Claim();
      $claim->setUser($this->getUser());
      $claim->setSP($sp);
      $claim->setStatus('New');
      $claim->setLastUpdated(new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
      $claim->setLastUpdatedBy($this->getUser()->getRealName() . ' (' . $this->getUser()->getId() . ')');

      $this->em->persist($claim);
      $this->em->flush();
      $this->_redirect(true, 'Your claim on that service provider account has been submitted for review. We will contact you with a status update after we review your request.', '/sp/makeClaim/');
    }
```